# Use SPAN to change color of a word if a definition is availible in the glossary

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm teaching myself JavaScript and JQuery and working through a simple Glossary app as I go.  Currently my glossary terms are in two json files (one for terms and one for acronyms).  I have a page with text on it and code to make a definition display in an alert when I click on a word that is available in the glossary of terms or glossary of acronyms.  That part is working.  What I would like to do is to be able to change the style of each word in the text that has a matching definition (color, underline, etc).  I think I need to use a loop to check if the word in in the glossary (I can already do that) and then apply  but I'm not really sure the span works when doing it dynamically.  The one span tag in my code is modified example that had been posted in another question here and I have it working for me, I'm just not too certain how it does what it does. Anyone have time to get me going in the right direction?

```
//breaks the paragraph html into word by word targets
var p = $('p#paragraph');
var words;
p.html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    words = oldHtml.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>')
    return words;
});
//when word is clicked checks to see if word in the glossary, if so displays alert box with word and definition
p.click(function(event) {
    if (this.id != event.target.id) {
          var termNeeded = event.target.innerHTML;
        //checks Terms json first
        var checkAcronyms = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonTerms.GlossaryTerms.length; i++) {
            var obj = jsonTerms.GlossaryTerms[i];
            if (obj.term == termNeeded) {
                alert(obj.term + ":  " + obj.definition);
                checkAcronyms = false;
                break;

         };
        };
        //if the word is not in the terms, then checks in the acronyms
            if (checkAcronyms == true){
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonAcronyms.GlossaryAcronyms.length; i++) {
            var obj = jsonAcronyms.GlossaryAcronyms[i];
            if (obj.term == termNeeded) {
                alert(obj.term + ":  " + obj.definition);
            break;
            };
            };
            };
        };

});

//brings in the JSON data
var jsonTerms;
$.getJSON("GlossaryTerms.json", function(data) {
    jsonTerms = data;
    //console.log(jsonTerms);
});

var jsonAcronyms;
$.getJSON("GlossaryAcronyms.json", function(data) {
    jsonAcronyms = data;
    //console.log(jsonAcronyms);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. How to style the span? `.word { color: blue; }` for example.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, instead of inserting the span element, just add a class to all words that come back as a match, and add a style in the the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this would do the trick:

I changed your code around a bit, and please beware that it is untested.

You would have to define a CSS style with the name `"defined"`, which will indicate that the word has a definition.

I extracted your logic into a separate function for reuse. Also, created the `addStyleToWords` function, which should iterate over all your words, check if they have a definition, and if they do, then add an extra class to that element.

```
var jsonTerms;
var jsonAcronyms;

function checkWord(termNeeded) {
    //checks Terms json first
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonTerms.GlossaryTerms.length; i++) {
        var obj = jsonTerms.GlossaryTerms[i];
        if (obj.term == termNeeded) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    //if the word is not in the terms, then checks in the acronyms
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonAcronyms.GlossaryAcronyms.length; i++) {
        var obj = jsonAcronyms.GlossaryAcronyms[i];
        if (obj.term == termNeeded) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
function addStyleToWords() {
    $(".word").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var obj = checkWord(el.text());
        if (obj != null) el.addClass("defined");
    });
}

//breaks the paragraph html into word by word targets
var p = $('p#paragraph');
p.html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>');
});
//when word is clicked checks to see if word in the glossary, if so displays alert box with word and definition
p.click(function(event) {
    if (this.id != event.target.id) {
        var obj = checkWord(event.target.innerHTML);
        if (obj != null) alert(obj.term + ":  " + obj.definition);
});

//brings in the JSON data
$.getJSON("GlossaryTerms.json", function(data) {
    jsonTerms = data;
    $.getJSON("GlossaryAcronyms.json", function(data) {
        jsonAcronyms = data;
        addStyleToWords();
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks, that is exactly what I was trying to do!  Thanks for reading through the holes in my question and helping me out here.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have added in your spans and the JSON data has loaded you need to loop through each
word span testing them for matches as you go.

```
p.find('span.word').each(function(){
    // "this" now refers to the span element
   var txt=this.innerHTML;
   if(isInGlossary(txt)){
    $(this).addClass('in_glossary');
   }
})
```

You will need to define the `isInGlossary(term)` function, pretty much what you have done already in your `p.click` code.

Comment: Pablo's answer pretty much sums it up. You might want to look at self [Memoizing functions](http://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/) to improve the efficiency of your checking function

Comment: Thanks!  This actually helped me make sense of Pablo's answer, which was overwhelming at first.  Certainly going to check out how to optimize this code.  I am worried that with the size of my finished text and glossary files I might be taking too long to do all this looping more than once!

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it...

To if I understand you correctly, look at: [JQuery addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

---

My Suggestions:

If you want to iterate over each work in the paragraph, then, in your click handler find each span tag using $('p#paragraph).find('span').each(function(){...});

In your each function, get the work with $(this).html()
To style your word, add a class or css to $(this). see:[JQuery addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Rather return your JSONArray as a JSONObject (much like an associative array) with the word being the property and the description being the value, that way you can search through it like so:  var definition = json[word].

Comment: Yes!  addClass is what I wanted. Thanks